# Python: Adding characters to strings error

Tags: python, string, attributeerror

I am creating a pseudo random encryption program, and IDLE returns and error when I try to expand my seed value. The  code goes like this.

```
for i in str(addon):
    seed = str(seed)
    seed.append(str(i))
    seed = int(seed)
```

When I run it, this happens.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any ideas on how I can add characters onto the end of a string?

Comment: `append` is used for lists. You can concatenate strings using `+`.

Comment: This snippet has no sense. I vote to delete this question because is confusing people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `append`. Append is for `list` objects.

```
seed += str(i)
```